# C++ How to add the sum from values in multiple if statements

Tags: c++

I'm having an issue in gathering and printing the total the sum(totalPrice) in my program.

The program repeatedly asks the user to enter ticket information and then calculates the total price for all the tickets entered.

If a ticket is requested to some other destination, the program informs the user that no tickets are available to that destination. The user can enter the city names as given or in all lower case.
The round trip price is the one-way price multiplied by 1.6. There is a 20% discount for students.
When the user enters the word “Done” or “done” when asked for the destination, the program outputs the total number of tickets and their total price and exits.

Everything is working fine as far as I know, except the final output of for total cost. Any help guys as to what I'm doing. I believe it might be my logic, but I'm too invested to see my mistake! Any help will be appreciated, thank you :)

```
using namespace std;

int main() {

    double totalPrice = 0; // the sum of all the values after the do while loop is done.
    int numberOfTicketsSold; // ehhhh counter?
    int counter; // keep track of the number of flights
    double temp = 0; // to hold the values while they're being adjusted
    double discount = 0; // another temp but for discount
    double boston = 350; // constant at 350 per trip
    double london = 600;
    double paris = 700;
    double tokyo = 800;

    string input; // might have to use char instead. Lets try it out anyways. 
    string roundTrip;
    string studentDiscount;

    cout << "**************************************************************" << endl;
    cout << "Enter the information for each ticket." << endl;
    cout << "When no more tickets to enter, enter 'Done' for destination." << endl;
    cout << "**************************************************************" << endl;

    do{

        cout << "Enter the destination city:" ; // Want to collect the string inputted to start if statements
        cin >> input;

        if ( input == "boston" || input == "Boston")
        {
            counter++; // keeps track of how many flights. For last output 
            cout << "\nRound trip? [Y/N]" << endl;
            cin >> roundTrip;
            if (roundTrip == "y" || roundTrip == "Y")
            {
                temp = boston; 
                temp = temp * 1.6;

            }
            else if(roundTrip == "n" || roundTrip == "N")
            {
                temp = boston;
            }

            cout << "\nStudent Discount? [Y/N]";
            cin >> studentDiscount;
            if (studentDiscount == "y" || studentDiscount == "Y")
            {
                discount = temp;
                discount = discount *.20;
                temp = temp - discount;
                totalPrice = temp;

            }
            else if(studentDiscount == "N" || studentDiscount == "n")
            {
             totalPrice = temp;// do nothing right? 
            }

        } 

        else if ( input == "london" || input == "London")
        {

            counter++; // keeps track of how many flights. For last output 
            cout << "\nRound trip? [Y/N]" << endl;
            cin >> roundTrip;
            if (roundTrip == "y" || roundTrip == "Y")
            {
                temp = london; 
                temp = temp * 1.6;

            }
            else if(roundTrip == "n" || roundTrip == "N")
            {
                temp = london;
            }

            cout << "\nStudent Discount? [Y/N]";
            cin >> studentDiscount;
            if (studentDiscount == "y" || studentDiscount == "Y")
            {
                discount = temp; // 600
                discount = discount *.20;
                temp = temp - discount;
                totalPrice = totalPrice + temp;

            }
            else if(studentDiscount == "N" || studentDiscount == "n")
            {
             totalPrice = totalPrice + temp;// do nothing right? 
            }

        } 

        else if ( input == "paris" || input == "Paris")
        {

            counter++; // keeps track of how many flights. For last output 
            cout << "\nRound trip? [Y/N]" << endl;
            cin >> roundTrip;
            if (roundTrip == "y" || roundTrip == "Y")
            {
                temp = paris; 
                temp = temp * 1.6;

            }
            else if(roundTrip == "n" || roundTrip == "N")
            {
                temp = paris;
            }

            cout << "\nStudent Discount? [Y/N]";
            cin >> studentDiscount;
            if (studentDiscount == "y" || studentDiscount == "Y")
            {
                discount = temp;
                discount = discount *.20;
                temp = temp - discount;
                totalPrice = temp;

            }
            else if(studentDiscount == "N" || studentDiscount == "n")
            {
             totalPrice = temp;// do nothing right? 
            }

        } 

        else if ( input == "tokyo" || input == "Tokyo")
        {

            counter++; // keeps track of how many flights. For last output 
            cout << "\nRound trip? [Y/N]" << endl;
            cin >> roundTrip;
            if (roundTrip == "y" || roundTrip == "Y")
            {
                temp = tokyo; 
                temp = temp * 1.6;

            }
            else if(roundTrip == "n" || roundTrip == "N")
            {
                temp = tokyo;
            }

            cout << "\nStudent Discount? [Y/N]";
            cin >> studentDiscount;
            if (studentDiscount == "y" || studentDiscount == "Y")
            {
                discount = temp;
                discount = discount *.20;
                temp = temp - discount;
                totalPrice = temp;

            }
            else if(studentDiscount == "N" || studentDiscount == "n")
            {
             totalPrice = temp;// do nothing right? 
            }

        } 


    } while (input != "done");

        cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------"<< endl;
        cout <<  counter << " tickets sold for a total sum of $" << temp << endl;
        cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------";

}
```

Comment: what is not working? Please describe what is the problem. Btw do you really want to print `temp` in the end and not `totalprice`?

Comment: What does it output? What do you want it to output?

Comment: OH MY GOD. Thank you guys. I was printing temp and not totalPrice!!!!!! I'm so dumb